# Should resource_owner/User-id be included in the OAuth 2.0 Access Token response?

Tags: web-services, authentication, oauth, architecture, oauth-2.0

This is a problem we are confronted with today. I looked online as much as I can before deciding to ask the question here.

The question is, when a user makes a "Access Token Request" with a username/password, should the Access Token response contain "user-id" field?

The [OAuth 2.0 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) says there can be an extra field (search for "example_parameter" in the spec) as part of the access token response. Can this extra field be user-id?

However, Many of the companies like facebook/google/twitter does not provide user-id as part of the access token response. User-id is provided as part of the validate token response.

What are the reasons for not providing user-id as part of the Access Token response? Why do we have to make another call (an extra round trip) if we need a user-id? What are the consequences of providing user-id as part of the Access Token response?

Answer (score 0):

Most applications don't want to leak their user-ids to the UI layer.  It is generally considered bad practice.  If you send the userid to the UI layer, the UI will have the ability to request information about that UserId, and get information about it back...

This presents a security issue, as the client can generally modify these calls to get information about other UserIDs...  If you are going to authenticate each call each time to validate that the token is bound to that user id, then it likely is a waste to have the client pass the userid itself, you are already doing the lookup, so you might as well keep the data internal to the service.

This also sets you up nicely to change your concept of a UserId in the future, maybe changing it to be group id, or an email address instead of the database userid...

Answer (score 0):

Oauth2.0 is an authorisation framework and doesn't deal with user authentication.

> The question is, when a user makes a "Access Token Request" with a
>   username/password, should the Access Token response contain "user-id"
>   field? In this context the resource

It's really a client requesting an access token and in many cases a client doesn't want to know about the id of the resource owner it just wants a token to allow it it call an endpoint on the resource server. The resource server can identity the user from the contents of the access token.

[OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) can be used to extend OAuth2.0 to include an ID token. This gives basic user info in a standard format without the need to call a further endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

An access token is a normally a bearer token that allows you to call an API. In OpenID Connect, you use the access token to call an api called the user_info endpoint, which returns a JSON object that contains information about the person, like first name, last name, etc. If you are looking for a free open source central authentication server that supports OAuth2, you should look at the Gluu Server http://gluu.org